# Javascript. Why need to put return keyword in line 2?... 12 is MATIC number and it will be divided by 4

Tags: javascript

In line 2, why need to put return keyword there ?... 12 is MATIC number and it will be divided by 4 ...

```
var quarter =function(number) {
    return number/4};  //why need to put return keyword here ?... 12 is MATIC number and it will be divided by 4 ...

if (quarter(12) % 3 === 0 ) {
  console.log("The statement is true");
} else {
  console.log("The statement is false");
}
```

Comment: [Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) and [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

Answer (score 1):

Otherwise the function wouldn't return an output value when called. For example, you could make several statements inside a function, like:

```
var quarter =function(number) {
    var foo = "bar",
        person = "john doe";

    return number/4;
}
```

Calling quarter(12) would still return the same thing.
You could also do

```
var quarter =function(number) {
    var result = number / 4;

    return result;
}
```

for example

Comment: return result; //what will happen to the result then?

Comment: it will return the value stored in the variable "result"... in this case,  ` var quarterOfTwelve = quarter(12)` produces the same effect as `var quarterOfTwelve = 12 / 4`, it returns a `number`

Answer (score 0):

When your if statement call quarter() function and pass 12 to it argument, than quarter() function do division operation on your argument number.

In your scenario quarter() function return 3 which is necessary for the if condition to modulo(%) with 3. So quarter() function is return a number( argument_number/4).

Add below code to print return value of quarter( ) function before if condition.

```
console.log(quarter(12));
```

So return value is necessary for the if condition to check return value is modulo(%) by 3 or not.